# OnClick of bitmap

Tags: java, android, bitmap, onclick

can you do an onClick of a Bitmap picture that you have created in the code or do I need to make my "zombie" the background of a texview etc. in order to preform the action on click?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need an `ImageButton` like this

```
<ImageButton
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:onClick="functionToCall"
        android:src="@drawable/to_top_button"
            />
```

And then define the function

```
public void functionToCall(View v) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: could you go to this page and help me with this question than?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10471881/can-you-make-an-image-button-move-in-the-same-was-as-a-bitmap-in-android